# Marquee doesn't move smooth

Tags: c#, wpf, marquee

I have created myself a small prototype for a marquee. It moves the label from the right edge of the screen to the left. Once there, it starts again at the right so that it looks infinite. Like a news ticker.

My problem is that, the label shifts its position very juddery. It just seems rude and bumpy. I move the label every 33 ms to 1.0 to the left.

My renderer running on the hardware side (Tier 2).
Framework: 4.5

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Canny.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="811" Name="main">
<Canvas Name="myCanvas" Background="Black">
    <Label Name="lb1" Content="Lauftext+++" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="618" Canvas.Top="10" FontFamily="Courier New" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontStretch="UltraExpanded"/>
</Canvas>
```

XAML.CS:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Canny
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    double newPos;
    readonly double actualWidthLb;
    int renderingTier;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33.0);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        newPos = myCanvas.ActualWidth;
        actualWidthLb = lb1.ActualWidth;
        timer.Start();
        renderingTier = (RenderCapability.Tier >> 16);

    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newPos -= 1.0;
        Canvas.SetLeft(lb1,newPos);
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(lb1) + actualWidthLb <= 0)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(lb1, myCanvas.ActualWidth);
            newPos = myCanvas.ActualWidth;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I thank you in advance about advices!

Comment: In WPF you should be using animations to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hard to get this smooth, the human eye is *very* sensitive to motion like this.  An evolutionary survival trait, keeps you well away from a hungry lion.  Drives people pretty nuts as well, a good reason to never use this in UI.  33 msec is about the worst possible value you can pick, timers tick with a interval that's a multiple of 15.625 msec on Windows.  Good values are multiples of that, rounded down.  So 15, 31, 46.  That's still going to cause you to miss a tick occasionally, be sure to always use actual elapsed time to calculate the increment.

Comment: Hey Hans Passant,
what do you mean with ' be sure to always use actual elapsed time to calculate the increment.' ?

Comment: Just don't assume that the timer consistently ticks with the rate you asked for.  It is going to be late some times, inevitably.  If you ignore this then motion is going to be jerky.  So use a Stopwatch to find out how much time *actually* passed since the previous tick.  Multiply by the desired velocity to get the increment.

Comment: Sorry Hans Passant, but I think I don't understand you right. I have to implement a stopwatch like that:
[pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/50257/csharp)
but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to lower the timer intervall? 33ms are about 30Hz. This rate is much too slow for our eyes to be experienced as a fluently moving picture. Our eyes are faster than this! Thats why you start at least witha rate of 50Hz (20ms) but for a real smooth experience you better start with 70Hz which is similar to 14ms or even faster. (frequency: f = 1/T). To adjust the scrolling speed you could lower the steps (e.g incrementing position value x = x - 0.1 -> slower or x = x - 0.01 -> 100x slower compared to incrementing x by -1.0) and vice versa.

You may consider to use your DispatcherTimer with a DispatcherPriority (via constructor) with a priority something like Render or higher...

But if you are using WPF why don't make use of the nice animation features provided? It's quickly and easily done with Blend. [MSDN - How to: Animate an Object Along a Path (Double Animation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746981%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: hey, I have adjust the rate, but it doesn't change my issue. The text is still bumpy and not smooth. I don't use animations because I think it must be possible to reach a marquee in this way.